# Node js library to manage response caching for application

Tags: node.js, caching

I am working with the API for an android application. They are implementing a library (fast android networking) that will avoid retaking responses if the headers say that old responses are still valid.

Now I am trying to implement a logic in my side that will be able to detect when a response has changed or not.
If the response has changed since the last time the application did the request, I set the appropriate headers to let the app know that their local response is invalid. Otherwise the header will let the application know that their local response is safe to use.

The application manages multimedia content. Users add their own content, share 
 content, subscribe to content etc. As a consequence, the responses for the application depend heavily on the user.

Considering this, I am not going to cache the responses. What I want to do is be able to tell the application when they will have to update the responses that they store locally.

We had a mechanism previously to do that. I was storing and updating the most recent time when a user was making a request on each one of the apis. Then I was updating a value that indicated the last time a particular set of data was being changed (ex if the list of songs was changing, or the info of a user was changing). This way I was able to understand (generally) if the application needed to replace their local responses or not.

However, that is lots of manual work, and maybe there are libraries out there that can handle it more efficiently. I have been searching, but everything I found does not consider the fact that responses change from user to user.

The backend is in Node js.

Comment: Do you have [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) enabled ?

Comment: Not right now. I could enable it.

Comment: @BrahmaDev OK, after doing some reading I got it. Etag generates this 'hash' or validation token that I can use to compare whether the response has changed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution consisted on using etags (at Brahma Dev's suggestion). I used the module crypto to generate the etag, sha256 as a hashing algorithm. On the back-end side, the logic goes like this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'); //include crypto
var evaluation_tag = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(result)).digest('hex'); //generate etag on api response
var client_etag = (!req.header('clientsETag')) ? "" : req.header('clientsETag'); //the application I am working with could not send the etag in any other manner
var status_code = (evaluation_tag!==client_etag) ? status : 304; // if the response data is different from the one in the application cache, send status different that 304
var response_data = (evaluation_tag!==client_etag) ? result : []; // if response has not changed, don't resend it to spare bandwidth and run time in both sides (client and server)

res.setHeader('etag', evaluation_tag);//send etag of new response
res.send(clear_response); //send response
```

The application receives the response. If status_code is 304, it ignores the rest of the response. Otherwise it updates the etag stored for this API as well as the data in the cache. If there is no etag and data in the cache, the application does not send an etag at all.

In the next request, the application sends the etag in its cache. The server calculates the etag of the new response. If it is the same as the one on the application, it means that the response is the same as well. 304 is sent as a status code and no data are sent back to the application. If the etag has changed, so have the data. Another status code (mostly 200, ... depends on the logic) is sent, along with the new data.

Express by default generates and sends etags. You can read more here. We chose to generate etags on our own for two reasons:

1. We did not want to use the hashing algorithms that express uses (md5 and crc32)
2. Express calculates the hash of the whole response. We have some parts of the response that might change in every response, though they do not represent the actual data for the application. That meant that even if the application data weren't changing, we were still getting the same etag every time.